# How to bind mouse wheel to all widgets in a scrollable Tcl canvas?

Tags: tcl

This is a piece of the code, that i have made, to bind my Tcl canvas to my mouse (MouseWheel event):

```
bind .top.f.c.canvas <MouseWheel> {
set delta [expr {- (%D / 120)}]
.top.f.c.canvas yview scroll $delta units
}
```

It's works well, when my mouse is on the canvas widget, i can scroll with the mouse the entire canvas.

But, if i place some widgets on my canvas, like: labels, entrys, text, etc., i can not trigger the Mousewheel event again,
because the widgets are now over my canvas, and my mouse is on this widgets (Enter) and not on the canvas.

Is there any way to trigger the event  to all widgets in my tcl window? Like if the mouse pointer is
on any widget, i wish use the wheel of the mouse to scroll the canvas.

thanks!

Comment: I suspect the easiest approach is to use `bindtags` to make a group if widgets that handle the mouse wheel in common.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason, I am using something similar to the following code, which invokes the first *MouseWheel* binding set on the widget hierarchy:

```
proc ProcessMouseWheel {w evt D X Y} {
    if {![winfo exists $w]} {
        return
    }
    set top [winfo toplevel $w]
    set grab [grab current]
    set wFired $w
    while {[winfo exists $w] && $w ne $top &&
           ($grab eq "" || [string match "$grab*" $w])} {
        foreach tag [bindtags $w] {
            if {$tag ne "all"} {
                set w_script [bind $tag $evt]
                if {$w_script ne ""} {
                    if {$w eq $wFired} {
                        # Event already processed
                        return
                    }
                    set x [expr {$X-[winfo rootx $w]}]
                    set y [expr {$Y-[winfo rooty $w]}]
                    catch [list uplevel #0 [string map [list %% % %W $w %D $D %X $X %Y $Y %x $x %y $y] $w_script]]
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        set w [winfo parent $w]
    }
}

bind all <MouseWheel> {ProcessMouseWheel %W <MouseWheel> %D %X %Y}
```

You can bind for *Shift-MouseWheel* or *Control-MouseWheel* too, but here no check is done for a less specific event called by specific event (*MouseWheel* binding triggered by *Shift-MouseWheel* event).